# Speed up rendering of simple Winforms custom component

Tags: c#, performance, winforms, user-controls

For our application we created a simple user component which consists of 2 panels, 4 labels and a checkbox. This is called a "ContactCard".

For each contact in our application we will instantiate such a contact card. The contacts are paged by maximum 50 per page.

The problem we're having is that the drawing is really slow on this.

I've looked around on SO and found a lot of people that have the same kind of issues. Some have them resolved with the `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout` options and others resolved it by tweaking the `OnPaint` method. We also tried to speed things up by having everything `async` and `await` the results.

These solutions however do not apply or do not work in our situation.
Does anybody have any pointers where we can look next?

Comment: What is a *user component*? One of `UserControl`, `Custom Control` or `Component` -- Paged how (code needed)? `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout` of what? -- Async / await may be used to load stuff asynchronously, but the rendering of Controls is synchronous. What takes more time?

Comment: Referring to *contacts* may imply you're showing images. If that's the case, using Panels? -- *50 cards per page* means that the previous 50 are, what, disposed? Removed from a collection? Other? (that's why code is needed here)